# Having trouble with Angular bootstrap ui modal windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interface with a "settings" button that opens a modal window. What I want to do is update scope values from the original controller. For example, in the MainController, i define a "default" theme that is used to control the theme in the body tag.

```
$scope.theme = 'default';
```

In the controller, I am updating the value of $scope.theme from an input in the view with something like ng-click"changeTheme(newValue)" .. which updates $scope.theme and furthermore, the body's class is reflected by this value.

```
<body ng-controller="MainController" ng-class="{midnight: theme == 'midnight'}">
```

Here is the modal code in that controller

```
$scope.open = function (settings) {
  $scope.settings = settings;
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    backdrop: true,
    windowClass: 'modal',
    controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {
      $scope.settings = settings;
      $scope.submit = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      settings: function () {
        return $scope.settings;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And in the view ... here's what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label>Label</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="settings.label" />
      <label>Value</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="settings.theme" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Close" />
    </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

This example works when sending back anything that is created in this new $scope.settings object. But what I want is for the new settings object to update the $scope.theme from the main controller as well. What am I missing?

Comment: I think people are having trouble understanding your question.  Please consider rewording.  We are missing the link between `theme` and settings.  I believe you said it was some logic contained within  `changeTheme()`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In attempting to re-word the question, I managed to find the answer I was looking for! I will post an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't give UI bootstrap nearly enough attention with their basic example. All I wanted was to find a way for the selection in the modal to update various scope values on the page. I've figured out out by messing with this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jpJX4WvHw0SSYm3pAAzq?p=preview

My trouble was understanding how to handle multiple variables changing from the modal. This is a very simple fork that illustrates what I was trying to initially understand:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RYNcURKjGhWxUBpUlAkD?p=preview